# Sort array with timestamps?

Tags: php, arrays, date, sorting, timestamp

I have an array of timestamps that look like this:

```
2012-11-19 19:45
```

I need to sort them by date. I could do a bubble sort or something if i could get the unix timestamp of a date, but i don't know what function gives me that. I looked at strtotime but it won't let me pass a date format. I'm also not sure a bubble sort is the best way to go.

Any suggestions?

Array example:

Also, sorry, i should have mentioned it was in 'show_date'.

```
Array
(
    [15] => Array
        (
            [show_date] => 2012-11-19 10:40
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [show_date] => 2012-11-20 10:40
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [show_date] => 2012-11-21 10:40
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [show_date] => 2012-11-22 10:40
        )

)
```

Comment: You don't need to write a bubble sort (that is one of the least efficient sorting algorithms). Just use one of PHP's built-in sorting functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to overcomplicate this. Just use the built-in `sort` function:

```
sort($timestamp_array);
```

**You don't need to convert to UNIX timestamps because the strings are in the standard "ISO sortable date" format.** That means that if you sort the strings, the dates will be in the correct order.

Here is a `php -a` session that shows how it works:

```
php > $ts = array('1986-01-31 12:11', '2012-01-01 13:12', '1980-10-10 12:00');
php > sort($ts);
php > echo var_export($ts);
array (
  0 => '1980-10-10 12:00',
  1 => '1986-01-31 12:11',
  2 => '2012-01-01 13:12',
)
```

Comment: asort() and sort() just returns true for some reason. Any ideas? See OP for array output example.

Comment: `sort()` does not return a sorted array, it returns whether the sort was successful. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php. It instead sorts the array *in place*, so your original array will contain the values in the right order.

Comment: Yea, my bad. It also didn't work because each date is placed within [show_date] in the array. I got it working, thanks! :)

Comment: Did it work? I've just seen the edit you made to the question and it looks like you'll need to use `usort()`.

Comment: Can this still be done if the timestamps are part of a multidimensional array?

Answer (score 1):

You can just sort it with PHP standard sort. See [Sorting Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)

```
asort($timestamps);
```

For your example, you can define a comparison function

```
function cmp_show_date($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['show_date'] == $b['show_date']) {
        return 0;
    }

    return ($a['show_date'] < $b['show_date']) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

and use that in [usort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

```
usort($timestamps, 'cmp_show_date');
```

Comment: asort() and sort() just returns true for some reason. Any ideas? See OP for array output example.

Comment: Look at [asort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) and [sort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php). "Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure." So, no surprise here.

Comment: @qwerty Look at my modified answer.

Comment: Your solution would probably work but i solved it by looping through the array and grabbing each value (`$array[x]['show_date'] = value`) and putting it in a new array (`$array[x] = value`), then copying the new array to the old one and resetting the temporary one. Then i just used sort() which worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need date format to pass that particular date. When you pass `strtotime('2012-11-19 19:45');` it will return UNIX time stamp.

**EDIT:**

```
$arr = array();
foreach ($dates as $k => $v) {
    $arr[$k]  = strtotime($v['date']);//or $k if your date is the index
}

array_multisort($arr, SORT_ASC, $dates);
```

Comment: So bubble sorting it is the best and simplest way?

Comment: @qwerty No, bubble sort is one of the slower algorithms. For a comparison look here [Sorting algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)

Comment: You can take advantage of the built in functions for sorting. See the solution in the edit of this post

Comment: This works quite well but you don't even need to call `strtotime()` - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.usort.php)() and [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.strtotime.php), but I'd rather use the [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/book.datetime.php) class and its [getTimestamp](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/datetime.gettimestamp.php) method because it can handle time zones and several formats.